# Should XML for a sitemap go in a separate XML file, or get included in my index.html?

Tags: xml, url, sitemap

google does not find my website. I want to create a sitemap, but I do not know how to make it. I have an example code. Must I save the sitemap on the server as a `.xml` file, or I should add the code to my `index.html` file, and if so, where?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
  <loc>http://www.rabotilnicakameya.com/index.html</loc>
   <lastmod>2021-11-22</lastmod>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: Your sitemap should  use `http://www.example.com/` rather than `http://www.example.com/index.html`.   The version with `index.html` is not the simplest preferred version of your URL.  Visitors should never see `index.html` in the URL.  You shouldn't include it in links, and you shouldn't tell Google about it in your sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

Your sitemap XML should be placed into a separate file called `sitemap.xml` and uploaded to the directory root of your web server, right next to your `index.html` file.   There is no way to include the XML directly in your `index.html` file.

However, having an XML sitemap is **NOT GOING TO HELP** your site get indexed by search engines. XML sitemaps can help large database driven websites with millions of pages get all their pages crawled.  However, Google rarely chooses to index a page just because it is listed in an XML sitemap.   Google usually chooses not to index pages unless they have links (including links from other pages on your site.)   If a page is indexed, the XML sitemap won't help it rank better.  Without links it will rank very poorly.   At best XML sitemaps give you extra stats in Google Search Console and tell Google about which URL versions you prefer.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox).

There are a variety of reasons that Google might not be indexing your site.  Most likely it is too new (less than 2 months old), it doesn't have any links from anywhere, the content is poor quality, or the content is found elsewhere on the web.  See [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

To get Google to index your site you should not focus on creating an XML sitemap.   An XML sitemap won't hurt, but it is unnecessary and won't solve the problem.  Instead you should:

- Write more pages
- Improve your existing pages
- Get links from other sites